# QGIS ImportPhotos plugin error

Tags: qgis

I've been using the ImportPhotos plugin for QGIS to add layers of geotagged photos. Initially, it works fine, but when I try to open the project after moving the project folder to another computer using a flash drive, sometimes the pictures won't show up. All the points are still on the map, but when I use the "Click Photos" tool to view the photos, they don't show.

I have confirmed that all the photos and files related to the photos layers are at the correct locations in the project folder after moving it. Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?